# iMAC Late 2009 - Only boots in Safe Mode

Tags: imac

iMAC Late 2009 - Gets stuck on Grey Screen with Apple Logo.

Only way to boot it is in Safe Mode

Ran Apple Hardware Test (Extended) - Came out Clean

Did Hard Drive Verify - No Issues

I have Reset PRAM

Out of ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had to take it to a Mac Repair Shop.  Bad Video Card. $180 to fix